# Postgresql set search_path doesn't affect despite the alter user set searh_path .... command

Tags: postgresql

Firstly, thanks in advance for your help.
I use PostgreSQL 12.6 on RHEL 7.9 with a 3-nodes patroni cluster.
I created a user with the name reader.

```
postgres=# CREATE USER reader LOGIN ;

CREATE ROLE

postgres=# GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA location TO reader;

GRANT

ALTER USER reader SET search_path TO location;

ALTER ROLE

postgres=# set role reader;

SET

postgres=> show search_path ;

   search_path   
-----------------
 "$user", public
```

I have also tried the following queries.

```
ALTER USER reader SET search_path = location;

ALTER USER reader SET search_path = 'location';

ALTER USER reader SET search_path TO 'location';


postgres=> show search_path ;

   search_path   
-----------------
 "$user", public
```

Comment: You have to connect as user reader to see their search path.

Comment: `set role` is not the same thing as actually logging in as that user.

Comment: Docs (set role): _SET ROLE does not process session variables as specified by the role's ALTER ROLE settings; this only happens during login_